# When should I set TTL index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, ttl

I want to user TTL index for a session collection. My question is that should I run `db.collection.createIndex()` only once when the server starts, or do I have to run the command every time after inserting new document?

For the latter instance, the code is like:

```
DB.findOneAndUpdate(args)
    .then((result) => {
        DB.createIndex({
            'name': 'sessions',
            'keys': {'lastLogin': 1},
            'options': {expireAfterSeconds: req.session.cookie.maxAge}
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: TTL index is primarily a simple index, with some additional option for time to live. So, you just have to create it once. You don't recreate indexes on every insert. We just create index once and thats it. Though in certain situation you want to drop indexes and recreate them but thats only in situations when you think your indexes are corrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is that should I run db.collection.createIndex() only once
>   when the server starts, or do I have to run the command every time
>   after inserting new document?

You shouldn't specify the TTL index on every insert. Create an index on a date type or an array of BSON date-typed objects and that index would be applied to every document. Also, you can modify the `expireAfterSeconds` of an existing TTL index using the `collMod` command. Checkout the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) for more detailed discussion.

Comment: so I could run the command only once when the server stars even the collection is empty, right?

Comment: Yes, just like other indexes

Answer (score 2):

When TTL index is created, there is no need to do extra stuff. 
Just insert document and wait to terminate.

### If you need to extend document lifetime then updated ttl indexed field accordingly.

If a document does not contain the indexed field, the document will not expire.